# Using Start/Stop-Transcript with Invoke-Command On Windows server 2012 R2 and 2016

Tags: powershell, remote-access, invoke, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

I am trying to do actions on servers remotely and log everyting using The transcript function.

**The Question is:** Is there a way to get the information of 2012 R2 servers (same a 2016) with start-transcript using invoke-command ? Or alternatively just print the powershell console output in a log file

Here's the logic :

```
function DoLogic() {
    #Algo / Actions
    Write-Host "TEST"
}

$servers = "server1","server2", "etc"

Start-Transcript -Path "E:\tmp\transcript.txt" -Verbose          
foreach ($server in $servers) {

    Write-Host "Server: " -NoNewline
    Write-Host "$server " -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock ${Function:DoLogic}   
}
Stop-Transcript
```

Implying that server1 is a 2012 R2 and server2 is a 2016

**The problem is that The output of the transcript is :**

Server:

server1

Server:

server2

INFO: Hello

---

**Powershell Console Output :**

Transcript started, output file is E:\tmp\transcript.txt

Server: server1

Hello

Server: server2

Hello

Transcript stopped, output file is E:\tmp\transcript.txt

---

Answer (score 1):

Try write-output instead of write-host